# How do you see what applications you've authorized on Stack Exchange with OAuth access?

Tags: support, api, oauth

I'm working on an app that integrates with Stack Exchange's OAuth interface, [as defined here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication). I can approve the application, but can't figure out how to find the apps that I've approved.

[image]

How do I disable or at least view this after I've approved it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply follow these steps (**updated for the new profiles**):

1. Go to your user profile on any Stack Exchange site (oddly enough, http://stackexchange.com itself doesn't provide access to this information - even though the information is identical across the entire network), eg: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current
2. Click the "edit profile and settings tab" (or just go directly to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current)
3. Go to the "Applications" tab. From here, you can view all authorized applications for your account and revoke access to a specific app.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I was looking around on stackexchange.com, since that's where you approve the app. I was able to find my app on another site like stackoverflow.

Comment: (I've edited this to make it up-to-date for the new profiles)

Answer (score 2):

On your profile, click on the "my apps" link

[image]

Or, use this [direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/user/apps/402098)

You can remove them from there:

[image]