# I can't log out of the Stack Exchange network. 

Tags: support, login

This might be hard to reproduce so I'm going to *carefully explain* what I'm doing, what I'm expecting to happen, and what happens instead. This whole episode has me concerned.

The whole incident began while I was logged into the Stack Exchange network with Firefox 13.0.1 on Windows 8 CP x64. I had previously authorized an API application to access my Stack Exchange inbox data and I revoked access to it (using [this method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134534/142114)).

I went to open the application (which isn't *really* an application - it's a web service) and of course, because the access token was invalid, I was redirected to the Stack Exchange authorization page. I wanted to test something, so I clicked the "log out" link at the top of the page:

[image]

So far so good - I was greeted with a page that stated:

> "Clicking Log Out will clear all local credentials in your browser."

Sounds good, so I clicked the orange "Log out" button:

[image]

This logged me out so I began the process of authorizing the application again - only to discover that I am suddenly logged in again.

What's going on?

---

**Edit:** I can reproduce this in Chrome 21.0.1180.15 dev-m.

Comment: Note: I originally though I had an answer to this (which I have since deleted) but I still keep automatically getting logged in again.

Comment: I'd test this to help, but having to relog in to every SE site ever on every device makes logging out extremely unnapealing

Comment: <insert Hotel California joke here>

Comment: @BenBrocka: But the irony is that it appears you *don't* get logged out :)

Comment: Maybe a work around for this would be that logging out on SE logs you out of all other SE sites. While logging out on a specific SE site, such as [so] or [su], logs you out of that site.

Comment: Why would anyone want to log out of SE?

Comment: SE doesn't support beta versions of web browsers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Firefox 13 is not a beta version.

Comment: Chrome 21.0.1180.15 dev-m is.

Comment: But, @Bryan, since *being* logged in is tracked using per-site cookies which cannot be removed by the global SE site, logging one out of all sites is a bit troublesome. (It's doable, of course, when always comparing the cookie values to some centralized authorization. But then [one of the goals](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274) of the global login was *"Site level logins must not fail if the global login system is down"*, so it might need extra work/fallback/..., and needs extra internal traffic for each request.)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, I log into SE (stackexchange.com) using an SE OpenID account, and I could log out of SE just fine -- but visiting the SE homepage again (to check that I had indeed logged out) would simply log me back in again. It may have something to do with the fact that I have 3rd-party cookies *disabled*.

The "problem" appears to be that logging out of SE doesn't actually remove the openid.stackexchange.com cookies. So visiting SE again will promptly log you in again. Also, I believe even removing the openid.stackexchange.com cookie won't log you out of individual sites like StackOverflow or SuperUser or even english.stackexchange.com if you're already logged in.

The most reliable way I've found to log out of the SE network completely is to remove every single StackExchange 'user' cookie from my system. The cookie has different names, but is usually `usr` or `englishuser` (for english.SE) or `somuser` (for meta.stackoverlow) or `se-user` (for SE itself) or something similar (see picture).

Until the SE devs implement a 'global logout' feature ([which](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195849/how-can-i-fully-log-out-of-all-stack-exchange-sites-so-i-dont-keep-auto-logging) [is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186488/logout-from-all-stack-exchange-accounts-is-not-working) [much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92326/how-to-log-out-completely-on-stackexchange-sites-using-openid-without-closing-my) [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86920/add-network-wide-logout-functionality)), a GreaseMonkey script would really come in handy -- anyone know of one? If I find some time, I'll try writing one myself.

[image: StackExchange and StackExchange site cookies]