# Can't logout from the site

Tags: bug, login, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't log out of the Stack Exchange network.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139036/i-cant-log-out-of-the-stack-exchange-network)

How do I logout from this site? There is no logout button, when I delete my cookies they keep coming back! How can I logout?

EDIT: I found the logout button but it keeps logging me in!

Comment: Can you extend on "it keeps logging me in"? Are you just visiting the home page and then seeing "Welcome back"? (That [would surprise me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/when-does-a-login-happen-automatically/140615#comment398693_140615).) Or are you actually clicking "login" and then being logged in without being asked for credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Just clear your Browser cookies. That said I can logout quite easily :/

Comment: That's barely a solution but rather an extremely ugly workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Go the the main stackexchange.com home page, click logout. Then you will be prompted to do another logout via a Orange button

Comment: that might be dump question but where is logou button?

Comment: @EXQStudio Hover over your username at the top of the page and look at the top middle-right of the menu that appears.