# Logout from all Stack Exchange accounts is not working

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, logout

I was logged on [Unix.StackExchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com). When I logged out from there, it showed me the following message:

> Clicking Log Out will clear our cookies and log you out on all devices.

I clicked on Logout button. But I am still not logged out from all other accounts, like [Meta.StackOverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and [StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

I tried it many times. But no result.

Although I first logged in using a Google account and did no log out from [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail).

What is the way to logout from all accounts using a single click?

Comment: It will log you out from `Unix.StackExchange.com` on all devices, not _all_ Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: `what is the way to logout from all accounts on a single click` - there isn't one.

Comment: related [Add “network wide logout” functionality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86920/add-network-wide-logout-functionality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till now there is no way to logout from all Stack Exchange accounts. The solution is to use incognito mode when logging in. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86920/add-network-wide-logout-functionality)

Comment: @Aziz Shaikh : Please don't make useless edits. You mayn't be bound to any edit review system since you have enough rep, make sure you don't misuse the rights.