# Where did 'My Apps' go?

Tags: support, stackapps

See [How do you see what applications you've authorized on Stack Exchange with OAuth access?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134532/188148)

This functionality seems to have moved with [the profile page update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226177/188148).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's still here, just go to `http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/apps/{your-user-id}`.

> [image]

Comment: I've edited the answer the OP linked to using your screenshot :)